# JavaFX - new ImageView and set method

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fxml, scenebuilder

I have to initialize a GridPane with new Object -> ImageView. With scenebuilder I put the property "onMouseClicked" the method "handleOnMouseClicked". But when I click restart game I delete all the ImageView on my board and I create new ImageView object without the handleOnMouseClicked method.. How should I do?

```
@FXML
   private void restartGame(ActionEvent event)throws Exception{
      myGrid.getChildren().removeIf(ImageView.class::isInstance);
      EventHandler<? extends Event> onClick = imgView.getOnMouseClicked(); 
      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){ //Per righe
         for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++){ // Per colonne
            myGrid.add(new ImageView().setOnMouseClicked(onClick), i, j); //String with error
         }
      }
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(black), 3, 3); // 4 pieces in the center of my grid
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(black), 4, 4);
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), 3, 4);
      myGrid.add(new ImageView(white), 4, 3);
      rd_p1_white.setSelected(false); // radiobuttons
      rd_p2_white.setSelected(false);
      rd_p1_black.setSelected(false);
      rd_p2_black.setSelected(false);
   }
```

Comment: BTW: Its better not to create a anonymus class just to add a initializer there. Simply assigning the new object to a variable should solve the problem. If you need to do this in multiple lines in your code, creating a method that creates the imageviews&initializes the event handler would be beneficial (DRY)...

Comment: Why not retrieve the `ImageView`s in those  `Grid`s and just add the `Image` to them?

Comment: You cannot add an image without a ImageView Object, I think!

Comment: I see other problem: the author couldn't understand where he should initialize mouse clicked handler, correct Alberto? Is this question still actual for you?